# Lag on fast typing and backspace on input fields in deployed Blazor code

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, code-reuse

I have created a reusable input field component in Blazor server application. When I run it in local, it is working fine. No issue in fast typing or backspace.

But when the same gets deployed, it is lagging on fast typing and fast backspace.
If I type too slow only then it is working.
The code I am using for reusable input component

```
<input placeholder="Input field" Class="form-control" @oninput="InputValueChanged" value="@Text" @onkeydown="Enter"/>
}

@code {  
    [Parameter]
    public string Text { get; set; } 
 
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> TextChanged { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> EnterButtonClicked { get; set; }
    
    public void Enter(KeyboardEventArgs keyboardEventArgs)
    {
        if(keyboardEventArgs.Code.Equals("Enter") || keyboardEventArgs.Code.Equals("NumpadEnter"))
        {
            EnterButtonClicked.InvokeAsync(Text);
        }
    }

    public async Task InputValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        Text = args.Value.ToString();
        await TextChanged.InvokeAsync(Text);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `Text` defined? Is it another parameter and you just forgot it?

Comment: @MisterMagoo He removed it (probably by mistake) in the last edit. It was indeed a parameter.

Comment: @MisterMagoo It was there , mistakenly remove it from here.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `@oninput` on Blazor Server Side. Which means everytime you type a character, `InputValueChanged` will be executed and through it you are gonna have some network time (+ execution time, probably negligible in your case, but would be an issue). If you are typing too fast, the process of the previously typed characters may not be finished.

Locally, there is no network time, this is why it works fine.

You have two possibilities:

- Use another event
- Try debouncing your event

[This](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14242) addresses this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the StateHasChanged(); isn't needed, and is causing the lag.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **@bind** for *OnInput* like

```
<input placeholder="Input field" Class="form-control" @bind-value:event="InputValueChanged" @bind-value="@Text" @onkeydown="Enter"/>
```